# LOKI logs ingest in InfluxDB

Tags: prometheus, grafana, monitoring, influxdb, grafana-loki

Is there a way we could ingest LOKI logs into influxdb for long-term storage? So I have Prometheus metrics and Loki logs both in the same place/DB for easy management.

Thanks